# python selenium click on button not working correctly, normal click by mouse is OK

Tags: python, selenium, tradingview-api

I use python to automate tradingview and I remove all alerts and set a new alert but it is not working. There appears a popup with two buttons `Yes` and `No`. Manual clicking by mouse is OK but using Selenium to click on the button but is not working.

```
#Remove all Alert
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-name='base']").click()
time.sleep(2) 
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-name='alerts']").click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-name='alerts-settings-button']").click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='item-RhC5uhZw item-YF9HXIe0 withIcon-RhC5uhZw withIcon-YF9HXIe0']").click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element(By.NAME,"yes").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#browser.find_element(By.NAME,"yes").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: At which line are you stuck?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "not working". Did you get any error-message?
Also include the url or page-source-code.

Comment: Normal click by mouse webpage remove all Alert; click by python using selenium it did not remove any Alert

Comment: how to send an image to help  ?

Comment: Please add the url, error message and also what element you to click on. Thanks

Comment: I using python to click on YES button or Sendkeys Enter but nothing happen https://www.dropbox.com/s/eajwqe016ha8fmk/screenshot_1675071376.png?dl=0     but click by mouse or press Enter by keyboard is OK

Comment: @DucDaoCong Do you mean Yes-> Accept all and No-> Decline?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?:

```py
browser.find_element(By.NAME,"yes").click()
```

Comment: Yes, it clickable and close popup, but not do anything. I try to send key ENTER, result is the same

Comment: Mhh maybe your button is inside some Iframe? Could you at least provide the url or page-scourcecode.